# Silent renew in oidc-client.js when we have extra query params

Tags: angular, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I am getting below error
[image]

I am having below UserManagerSettings

```
private getClientSettings(loginType?): UserManagerSettings {
    let logout;
    if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('loginType') === 'Internal') {
      logout = environment.post_logout_redirect_uri + 'biz-admin';
    } else {
      logout = environment.post_logout_redirect_uri;
    }

    return {
      authority: environment.authority,
      client_id: environment.client,
      redirect_uri: environment.redirectUri,
      post_logout_redirect_uri: logout,
      response_type: 'id_token token',
      scope: environment.scopes,
      filterProtocolClaims: true,
      silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/assets/silent-refresh.html',
      loadUserInfo: true,
      extraQueryParams: {
        loginType: loginType,
      },
    };
  }
```

Below adds an expiring event

```
this.manager.events.addAccessTokenExpiring(x => {
  this.renewToken().then(u => {
    this.user = u;
  });
});
```

Below functions call sign in silent

```
 public renewToken(): Promise<User> {
    return this.manager.signinSilent(this.getClientSettings('Internal'));
  }
```

Silent-refresh.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oidc-client/1.7.0/oidc-client.js"></script>
<script>
  var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager();
  mgr.signinSilentCallback().catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
</script>
```

URI, I have custom logic based on loginType

```
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fassets%2Fsilent-refresh.html&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&state=307b01d8e3234027b92e0f2920364d4a&nonce=c8d110e677bd4fc8a993b77798893edf&prompt=none&loginType=undefined
```

Also, I have correct redirect URI in the database, still, renew do not work. `renewtoken()` gets called but never comes back to 'then' code.

Questions -

1. How does silent renew manages to get access_token? does it take saved id password from somewhere?
2. How can I send extra query params to `signInSilent()` it is undefined even after I am passing it as params, how does `signInSilent()` gets the user manager setting?

Comment: If I use automaticsilentrenew: true I do not get frame timeout error but login type is still undefined, and where can I receive the user in that case? I added user load event but it did not trigger after silent renew get called.

Comment: I observed this error comes http://localhost:4200/assets/silent-refresh.html#error=login_required&state=8d9934fc15cc44da9927fd940efc4586

with below request authorize?client_id=GhipLocal&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fassets%2Fsilent-refresh.html&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&state=8d9934fc15cc44da9927fd940efc4586&nonce=20d96f83442b4a69aa4e13706338c3e5&prompt=none&loginType=undefined

Also response type is id_token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by following steps-

Startup

```
 services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;
            })

services.AddAuthentication(x => x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

Logout

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model) { await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);}
```

There is nothing at the angular side, we need to configure the above setting at identity server code

Thanks to below user's comment
https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/911#issuecomment-617724445